# Azure web service throwing HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, azure, http

i need help in solving below error, it was working since until 2 weeks and suddenly we are getting this error. We are not able to call the azure webservice in C#.NET code,

**Webserice :** https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/aca19128d0a54309a75f5be4052c34a9/services/aee04e32d13d435d8d53b518b8504c5b/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true

```
Exception:
Inner Exception Type: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Inner Exception: An error occurred while sending the request.
Inner Source: mscorlib
Inner Stack Trace:
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at max_data.d__3.MoveNext() in d:HARDCASTLE_OFFICE_2019Hardcastle_Work_2019_VS2012mckinseyhandlermax_data.ashx:line 281
Exception Type: System.AggregateException
Exception: One or more errors occurred. 
Source: max_data
Stack Trace:
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
at max_data.get_r_Data(String uid) in d:HARDCASTLE_OFFICE_2019Hardcastle_Work_2019_VS2012mckinseyhandlermax_data.ashx:line 137
```

The Page Code I use to make this request is below:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="max_data" %>
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;


public class max_data : IHttpHandler {
    private MySqlConnection myAccessConn = null;
    MysqlDBInteraction Interaction = new MysqlDBInteraction();
    public static string arrayvalue = string.Empty;
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
        //View propery Details
        string abc = context.Request["MAXDATA"];
        if (abc != "" && abc != null)
        {
            context.Response.Write(get_r_Data(abc));
        }
    }
    private string d_Data(string uid)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //Code for insert survey
            string surveyid = string.Empty;
            string[] str_surveyarray = uid.Split('*');
            string[] sarray = str_surveyarray[1].Split('#');
            string insert_surveyquery = "INSERT INTO `ADMIN_SURVEY_TBL`(`SURVEY_NAME`, `SURVEY_TYPE`, `ACTIVE`, `CREATED_BY_ID`,`QUESTION_TEXT`,`SHOW_FLAG`) VALUES ('" + sarray[0] + "','MaxDiff Survey','Y','" + sarray[2] + "','In each card given below,  select the options MOST PREFERRED & LEAST PREFERRED by you.','N');SELECT MAX(`SURVEY_ID`) as `SURVEY_ID` FROM `ADMIN_SURVEY_TBL`";
            string survey_res = InsertData(insert_surveyquery);
            if (survey_res.Split('|')[0] == "SUCCESS")
            {
                surveyid = survey_res.Split('|')[1];
            }
            else
            {
                surveyid = "0";
            }
            //
            //Code for Write the CSV file
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string[] straary = str_surveyarray[0].Split('#');
            for (int i = 0; i < straary.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(FormatCSV(straary[i].ToString()));
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
            string uriPath = "DATA/DATA.csv";//_IPHONE/MCKINSEY
                                             //string uriPath = "http://hardcastlegis.co.in/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/amol28_132_LEVEL.csv";//_IPHONE/MCKINSEY
            uriPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(uriPath);
            File.WriteAllText(uriPath, sb.ToString());
            //code ends here
            //File.WriteAllText("http://hardcastlegis.co.in/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/final_data.csv", sb.ToString());
            //InvokeRequestResponseService().Wait();
            response = surveyid +"|"+ arrayvalue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "max_data");
            ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(ex);
        }
        return response;
    }
    public static string FormatCSV(string input)
    {
        try
        {
            if (input == null)
                return string.Empty;

            bool containsQuote = false;
            bool containsComma = false;
            int len = input.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < len && (containsComma == false || containsQuote == false); i++)
            {
                char ch = input[i];
                if (ch == '"')
                    containsQuote = true;
                else if (ch == ',')
                    containsComma = true;
            }

            if (containsQuote && containsComma)
                input = input.Replace("\"", "\"\"");

            if (containsComma)
                return "\"" + input + "\"";
            else
                return input;
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    private string get_r_Data(string uid)
    {
        string response = string.Empty;
        string[] strvar_aaray = uid.Split('*');
        string surveyid = strvar_aaray[0].Trim();
        string level_csv = strvar_aaray[1].Trim();
        string data_csv = strvar_aaray[2].Trim();
        string no_of_features = strvar_aaray[3].Trim();
        string no_of_cards = strvar_aaray[4].Trim();
        try
        {
            int no_featurs = Convert.ToInt32(no_of_features);
            InvokeRequestResponseService(no_featurs,level_csv,data_csv).Wait();
            response = surveyid + "|" + arrayvalue;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "max_data");
            ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(ex);
        }
        return response;
    }
    static async Task InvokeRequestResponseService(int no_features, string level_csv, string data_csv)
    {
        //code for no of features 3 or 4 or 5//test100_124_DATA//test100_124_LEVEL
        string authenication_url = string.Empty;
        int val = 1;
        if (no_features == 3)
        {
            authenication_url = "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/aca19128d0a54309a75f5be4052c34a9/services/aee04e32d13d435d8d53b518b8504c5b/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true";
            //authenication_url = "https://services.azureml.net/workspaces/aca19128d0a54309a75f5be4052c34a9/webservices/20130f84ec3e43d9805fea5f98f1d423/endpoints/default?fromStudio=true";
            //apikey_str = "Qn83z7Lq10SixRAYAWEjnwfnuxVTyDR3GQsYj1FehXPXvhGEGLNLVva/ldnodNJ3kSoxKxPQnBsvB84vIoHT8Q==";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var scoreRequest = new
                {
                    GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "Data source URL1", "http://103.224.247.79/mckinsey/PHP/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/"+data_csv+"" },
    { "Data source URL", "http://103.224.247.79/mckinsey/PHP/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/"+level_csv+"" },
}
                };
                const string apiKey = "Qn83z7Lq10SixRAYAWEjnwfnuxVTyDR3GQsYj1FehXPXvhGEGLNLVva/ldnodNJ3kSoxKxPQnBsvB84vIoHT8Q=="; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(authenication_url);

                // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
                // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false) so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
                // For instance, replace code such as://http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATA.csv
                //      result = await DoSomeTask()
                // with the following://http://hardcastlegis.co.in/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/final_data.csv
                //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)
                //http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATA.csv
                //http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATACSV.csv

                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, authenication_url);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    arrayvalue = result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));

                    // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

                    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (no_features == 4)
        {
            authenication_url = "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/aca19128d0a54309a75f5be4052c34a9/services/a98fd224e6e44331989944b460112171/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true";
            //apikey_str = "kPfZ4KCpo30bTFDn57U+T1gTY33bioA7dziEHp5xgLzbHtZmIOdeP6w0uRGZgEazR9/hXnygCI/MqlW7mtsrMw==";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var scoreRequest = new
                {
                    GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "Data source URL1", "http://103.224.247.79/mckinsey/PHP/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/"+data_csv+"" },
        { "Data source URL", "http://103.224.247.79/mckinsey/PHP/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/"+level_csv+"" },
}
                };
                const string apiKey = "kPfZ4KCpo30bTFDn57U+T1gTY33bioA7dziEHp5xgLzbHtZmIOdeP6w0uRGZgEazR9/hXnygCI/MqlW7mtsrMw=="; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(authenication_url);

                // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
                // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false) so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
                // For instance, replace code such as://http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATA.csv
                //      result = await DoSomeTask()
                // with the following://http://hardcastlegis.co.in/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/final_data.csv
                //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)
                //http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATA.csv
                //http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATACSV.csv


                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    arrayvalue = result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));

                    // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

                    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
            //code for no of features is 5
            //authenication_url = "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/aca19128d0a54309a75f5be4052c34a9/services/72a80928c1564d75a89589c64fe865c3/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true";
            authenication_url = "https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/aca19128d0a54309a75f5be4052c34a9/services/72a80928c1564d75a89589c64fe865c3/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true";
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var scoreRequest = new
                {
                    GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                            { "Data source URL", "http://103.224.247.79/mckinsey/PHP/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/"+level_csv+"" },
                            { "Data source URL1", "http://103.224.247.79/mckinsey/PHP/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/"+data_csv+"" },
                    }
                };
                const string apiKey = "XUWQv5oMfFOKhwOJwWNXYw7Tfgu4r2hHhil4Clu6CBcoEPhCWaVNgT6qeMtFEt/pRfbhV5Z2jeRxV/1pKNTWbw=="; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ussouthcentral.services.azureml.net/workspaces/aca19128d0a54309a75f5be4052c34a9/services/72a80928c1564d75a89589c64fe865c3/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true");

                // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
                // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false) so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
                // For instance, replace code such as:
                //      result = await DoSomeTask()
                // with the following:
                //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)


                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));

                    // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
                    Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

                    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message);
        }
        return;
        //apikey_str = "XUWQv5oMfFOKhwOJwWNXYw7Tfgu4r2hHhil4Clu6CBcoEPhCWaVNgT6qeMtFEt/pRfbhV5Z2jeRxV/1pKNTWbw==";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var scoreRequest = new
            {
                GlobalParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
        { "Data source URL1", "http://103.224.247.79/mckinsey/PHP/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/"+data_csv+"" },
        { "Data source URL", "http://103.224.247.79/mckinsey/PHP/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/"+level_csv+"" },
}
            };
            const string apiKey = "XUWQv5oMfFOKhwOJwWNXYw7Tfgu4r2hHhil4Clu6CBcoEPhCWaVNgT6qeMtFEt/pRfbhV5Z2jeRxV/1pKNTWbw=="; // Replace this with the API key for the web service
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", apiKey);

            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(authenication_url);
            /*http://hardcastlegis.co.in/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/CV Demo_17_DATA.csv
            http://hardcastlegis.co.in/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/SAVE_SURVEY/CV Demo_17_LEVEL.csv*/

            // WARNING: The 'await' statement below can result in a deadlock if you are calling this code from the UI thread of an ASP.Net application.
            // One way to address this would be to call ConfigureAwait(false) so that the execution does not attempt to resume on the original context.
            // For instance, replace code such as://http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATA.csv
            //      result = await DoSomeTask()
            // with the following://http://hardcastlegis.co.in/_IPHONE/MCKINSEY/final_data.csv
            //      result = await DoSomeTask().ConfigureAwait(false)
            //http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATA.csv
            //http://hardcastlegis.in/mckinsey_new/handler/DATA/DATACSV.csv


            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("", scoreRequest);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                arrayvalue = result;
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", result);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));

                // Print the headers - they include the requert ID and the timestamp, which are useful for debugging the failure
                Console.WriteLine(response.Headers.ToString());

                string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
            }
        }
    }
    //ends here

}
public class StringTable
{
    public string[] ColumnNames { get; set; }
    public string[,] Values { get; set; }
}
//database
public bool GetConnection(string connString)
{

    string Error = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        myAccessConn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
        myAccessConn.Open();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Error = "ERRR|" + ex.Message;
        //Write error information in ErrorLog.xml file
        ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "MysqlDBInteraction");
        ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
public void CloseConnection()
{
    try
    {
        if (myAccessConn == null)
            return;
        if (myAccessConn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            myAccessConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //ex.Message;
        ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "MysqlDBInteraction");
        ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(ex);
    }
}
public string GetStringFomXML(string tagName)
{
    string Response = string.Empty;
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();

    try
    {
        //Load xml file.
        xmldoc.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("HDCONNECT") + "\\Connectionpath.xml");
        for (int _Count = 0; _Count < xmldoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes.Count; _Count++)
        {
            if (xmldoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[_Count].Name == tagName)
            {
                Response = xmldoc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[_Count].InnerText.ToString();
            }
        }
        //Response = "Server=103.21.58.5;Port=3306;Database=test_mysql;Uid=testuser;Pwd=Testuser5@9960;";
        //Response = "Server=103.21.58.5;Port=3306;Database=hardcast_PROPERTY_TAX;Uid=propertyuser;Pwd=Property@9960;";
        return Response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response = "ERROR|" + ex.Message;
        //Write error information in ErrorLog.xml file
        ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "MysqlDBInteraction");
        ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(ex);
        return Response;
    }

}
public string InsertData(string insertQuery)
{
    MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand();
    //OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand();
    try
    {
        string connString = GetStringFomXML("Connection");
        bool CheckConn = GetConnection(connString);

        if (CheckConn)
        {

            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            comm.Connection = myAccessConn;
            comm.CommandText = insertQuery;

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            long lastid = comm.LastInsertedId;
            return "SUCCESS| " + lastid.ToString() + "";
        }
        else
        { return "ERROR|Unable to connect database. Please try again."; }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionUtility.LogException(ex, "MysqlDBInteraction");
        ExceptionUtility.NotifySystemOps(ex);
        return "ERROR|" + ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        comm.Cancel();
        comm.Dispose();
        CloseConnection();
    }
}
//ends
public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}

}
```

from above code I  get InvokeRequestResponseService function use for call servcie

Comment: Would you kindly provide your request code sample on your question?

Comment: Hi, I have added the code to my question @MdFaridUddinKiron . Thanks

Comment: Hi @Keeda, Are you still having problems?

Comment: Hi, we resolved the issue, there was an issue with the .net version we are using.